# Emulator to run an application as if its on a different CPU

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, emulator

Can anyone recommend an emulator (ideally open source and available for Debian 9 or RHEL7) which would allow me to run a program as if it is running on a slightly different CPU?
I typically use virtual-box for VMs but this does not provide much control over the actual CPU used.
Specifically I would like to compare:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5504
  and
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU

Though I can imagine a few other uses for this relating to sandboxes.
Ideally I'd like to be able to take a command and just run it under emulation a bit like you do with valgrind but a VM would be okay as well. E.g.

```
/bin/ls
valgrind --tool=memcheck /bin/ls
<magicemu> --cpu XeonE5504 /bin/ls
```

I imagine I want to use something like [Bochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochs) or [qemu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU). Those might be suitable with some guidance or a convenience wrapper of some kind.

In this instance it would be enough to just trap just the floating point operations.

### Background

I have an application in which I've observed different behaviour on two different platforms. I've narrowed it down to the point that I think the difference is caused by the floating point implementation in the hardware on two different CPU.

This led me to ask:

- [how-to-detect-differences-in-floating-point-behaviour-across-platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300378/how-to-detect-differences-in-floating-point-behaviour-across-platforms)
  and
- [how to force use of software floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225910/software-floating-point-and-x87-or-sse-disabled)

The root cause which should be addressed is floating point code which makes no attempt to be portable. This is out of my control but I would like to be able to demonstrate that it is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a GUI wrapper for KVM/QEMU called [Virt-Manager](https://virt-manager.org/). It looks like you can [select different CPU models](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/sec-virt-manager-tuning-cpu-config) to emulate.

Comment: This looks promising. It doesn't have an option for a Xeon (on my system). Any idea what the nearest hardware from the list would be? Or maybe something known to be old and buggy?

Comment: @BruceAdams Sorry, not sure. I've only used it for basic VMs.